# Which Power Armor is the most cost effective in terms of repair?

Tags: fallout-4

I've been running into problems repairing my power armor because I don't have much aluminum and circuitry to repair it.

I want to find a Power Armor that is cheap to repair, but is also strong in battle, i.e. can withstand a beating. I tried using T-45 power armor but it's too weak in battle, the parts break too easily.

Which suit offers the most cost effective repair to strength ratio?

Comment: You'll have to be a bit more precise with your request. What is "cheap", what is "strong"?

Comment: Basically, I want to use Power Armour which doesn't use much materials in repair and could withstand a 10 min battle without breaking on me.

Comment: 10 minute battles? You got any gun with Explosive legendary effect?  Try using it.

Answer (score 10):

The level your power armor is upgraded to does not influence the repair cost (in my experience, wiki confirms), so if you haven't already done so, get your Armorer and Science built up so you can get to F or Mk. VI, as this will result in a marked increase in defensive rating without any additional repair costs.

Here are all the fully upgraded power armor sets (excluding uniques), including defensive values and repair costs:

```
Power Armor  | Physical | Energy | Radiation | Full Repair Cost
Raider II    | 620      | 250    | 1050      | 20 Steel
T-45f        | 1100     | 910    | 1050      | 27 Steel, 1 Circuitry
T-51f        | 1340     | 1090   | 1050      | 33 Steel, 1 Aluminum, 1 Circuitry
T-60f        | 1580     | 1245   | 1050      | 40 Steel, 8 Aluminum, 8 Plastic, 1 Circuitry
X-01 Mk. VI  | 1820     | 1390   | 1050      | 45 Steel, 16 Aluminum, 5 Copper, 2 Circuitry
```

The difference between T-45f and T-51f is negligible in terms of Aluminum (0 for T-45f and 1 for T-51f), but with a pretty substantial defensive boost. So, if you're using T-45 right now, I'd say go for T-51.

Last but not least, consider applying the Winterized Coating to boost your Energy Resistance (+20 with all pieces painted). It's not much but it doesn't add anything to the repair costs.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the X-01 has an upgrade available for it that works similarly as an energy resistant plating, but is not as expensive to create.  Also, taking the perk that lets you recover more and better components (IIRC, "Scrapper") resolves the circuitry issue with repairing PA.

Comment: if you're running short on Aluminum, keep an eye out for shiny cans and silver 'TV dinner' trays. Raid as many diners and general stores as you can.

Comment: Also learn how the component tagging works and tag **everything** you use.  You can then quickly determine whether to grab that random loot or not.